# Dynamic Cast Class Unconditional issue parsing json in SWIFT

Tags: ios, json, swift, int, dynamic-cast

I have a json, it's complicated but I need to get the width of some pictures.

I have 12 images in the json.
Everything works fine for the first 10, but I have a crash for the 11th.

```
"sizes": [
{   "height": "2932",
    "url": "myurl",
    "width": "645"
},
```

My code is :

```
var width : Int!

if let jsonResult: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,options:nil,error: nil) {

    if jsonResult is NSDictionary {
        if let allPosts = jsonResult["posts"] as? NSArray { // récup tous les posts dans l'Array allPosts

            for posts in allPosts {
                if let jsonMedia = posts["media"] as? NSArray {
                     if let allMetaSizes = jsonMedia[0]["sizes"] as? NSArray {
                           for sizes in allMetaSizes {
                               if size=="full" { // image taille normale
                                   width = sizes["width"] as Int //CRASH
                                }
                            }
                       }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

I get :

```
EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_i386...)
swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional
```

I suppose it's a problem when I cast the AnyObject to Int, but why does it work for the first pictures ?

I don't find how to solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error can be interpreted as the `width` key not found in the `sizes` dictionary, or the corresponding value not of `Int` type.

A quick fix is to avoid forced cast, and replace it with a conditional cast - that requires turning `width` into an optional:

```
var width : Int?

if let jsonResult: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,options:nil,error: nil) {

    if jsonResult is NSDictionary {
        if let allPosts = jsonResult["posts"] as? NSArray { // récup tous les posts dans l'Array allPosts

            for posts in allPosts {
                if let jsonMedia = posts["media"] as? NSArray {
                    if let allMetaSizes = jsonMedia[0]["sizes"] as? NSArray {
                        for sizes in allMetaSizes {
                            if size=="full" { // image taille normale
                                width = sizes["width"] as? Int
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now `width` can contain either a valid `Int` value or `nil` - just use optional binding to do whatever you need to do with it when not `nil`:

```
if let width = width {
    ... do something with width
}
```

However I suggest you putting a breakpoint on the line causing the exception, to figure out why the forced cast fails - alternatively, you can just print it:

```
println(sizes["width"])
```

**Addendum** If the value contained in the dictionary is of string type, try replacing this line:

```
width = sizes["width"] as? Int
```

with

```
let strWidth = sizes["width"] as? String
width = strWidth?.toInt()
```

Comment: I followed your instructions. It doesn't crash anymore but println(sizes["width"]) prints Optional(645), and below, println(width) prints nil. Why width is nil ? I need to use width later in my app.

Comment: That probably means `sizes["width"]` cannot be cast to an int. I suggest adding the value extracted from the dictionary to a local variable, and inspect it in a debug session `let val = sizes["width"]`

Comment: I don't know what that means : Printing description of val:
(AnyObject?!) val = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x7afb5c00 -> 0x01114358 (void *)0x01114330: __NSCFString)

Comment: That means it's a string, which cannot be cast to `Int` - reason why `width` is nil. See updated answer for a workaround

Comment: Yes you're right ! I didn't notice that my json returns the width in String for the 11th picture. For the others pictures, my son returns an Int. Strange...

Comment: Your son returns an Int? I take that as a mistype... ;-) Btw glad it worked